# Custom docker image has huge size growth

Tags: docker

A ubuntu:16.04 image has 117 MB:

```
$ docker images

ubuntu 16.04 6a2f32de169d 5 days ago 117 MB
```

With this Dockerfile I want to add some packages (python, build-essentials and curl) and meteor:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install python -y
RUN apt-get install build-essential -y
RUN apt-get install curl -y
RUN cd ~ && curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

After building the new image...

```
docker build -t custom-ubuntu .
```

... I see it has more then 1 GB. I don't understand this huge amount...

**Second attempt**

Using this Dockerfile...

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install nodejs-legacy -yqq
RUN apt-get install curl -yqq
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get autoclean && apt-get autoremove
RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

... starts with 1.2 GB and at least a result of 850 MB.

This is the beginning of the output, so apt-get update should add just 24MB...

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 1.202 GB
Step 1/6 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 6a2f32de169d
Step 2/6 : RUN apt-get update -y
 ---> Running in 4c4cec841f5d
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Sources [9802 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1558 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages [14.1 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages [9827 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Sources [187 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Sources [30.0 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [652 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [13.2 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [577 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [9809 B]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages [4929 B]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages [2567 B]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [308 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages [12.8 kB]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [133 kB]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [2936 B]
Fetched 23.9 MB in 7s (3184 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y`. This is upgrading the entire system to latest version of all installed packages. I think you need only to do `apt-get update` and then install desired packages. Why to upgrade entire system? In a container is enough if what you want is working or is recommended to update if you know there is some kind of vulnerability on any of packages you are using on that versions. Anyway, python has a lot of dependencies you know, the size is increased if you install it.

Another good practice to reduce the container's size is to add this to Dockerfile (after all other apt-get statements):

```
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get autoclean && apt-get autoremove
```

With these apt-get commands you are cleaning and removing all downloaded .deb package files.

Do it and check the size after all of these recommendations. Good luck.

Comment: Updated the post with the second attempt

Comment: It says `Sending build context to Docker daemon 1.202 GB` . What do you have on that folder? the folder of Dockerfile should be empty or only with the things you need for the container building